# Two week notice excel

Tags: excel

I am managing project due dates for respective students and I need the last column, “target date” to show a two week due date notification.  The notification just means the row's "target date" turns red as soon as there is a two week period before the stated date.

Here is what it looks like:

```
A              B            C  
John Doe       1/17/2016    4/1/16  (needs to turn red)  
Bob JoeBob     7/1/2016     7/28/16 (needs to turn red)  
Corny Steve    7/1/2016     7/30/16 (still normal font)
```

Any help would be greatly  appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Highlight cells you want it to apply to, create a new rule in the conditional formatting drop-down menu, then write the formula =TODAY()+14